# How to return json formatted results for join query in postgres

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, join

I have this existing query:

```
SELECT to_json(table1) FROM table1
```

To return all of table in a nice json format. I need to add a join to this query, so my new query looks something like this:

```
SELECT (field1, field2, table2field1)
     FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON field1 = table2id;
```

How can I get a similar style output in json format for this new query ? to_json no longer works.

Previous overflow questions like this do not show how to return all rows.

Comment: Re (re)search success: Please before considering posting: Pin down code issues via [mre]. Read the manual/reference & google any error message & many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular names/strings/numbers, 'site:stackoverflow.com' & tags; read many answers. Reflect research in posts. SO/SE search is poor & literal & unusual, read the help. Google re googling/searching, including Q&A at [meta] & [meta.se]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: How is googling, say, your title, as-is or per my comments, not giving you answers? [How to transform a postgresql select with join to a json object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70194301/3404097) (Etc.)

Answer (score 1):

you can try

```sql
WITH EXAMPLE (COL1,COL2,COL3) AS (
 SELECT field1, field2, table2field1
 FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON field1 = table2id
)
SELECT TO_JSON(E) FROM EXAMPLE E;
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without a CTE. Use your query w/o brackets round the select list in the `from` clause

```sql
select to_json(t) from (... your select query here ...) t;
```

i.e.

```sql
select to_json(t) from
(
 SELECT field1, field2, table2field1
 FROM table1
 INNER JOIN table2 ON field1 = table2id
) t;
```

Comment: I used this approach and it worked. Awesome, thank you